# There's no React JS autocomplete with "inline suggestion & Preview" in textarea? how to implement it

Tags: reactjs, forms, user-input, autosuggest

## React JS autocomplete with "inline suggestion & Preview" in textarea

Just like what github copilot do in Vscode

[image]

I want to build a simple Language Model based conversation text completion
So the multiple choice inline completion like
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@webscopeio/react-textarea-autocomplete

didn't really work

## what I would like is a plain text-area with a suggestion support

what I want is REAL INLINE just the text with transperent concat to the input just like Co-Pilot
I've found react-inline-autocomplete Forked it and update the versioning
It's good really good! and ALMOST fit my needs but
https://github.com/HRNPH/react-inline-autocomplete

Example here: https://kyuch4n.github.io/react-inline-autocomplete/

It didn't really use 'text-area' but instead 'input' so this would work for form-data
but not for long content such as article or something similar

Is there an alternative to this? or how can I Implemented the same behaviour in TextArea?